# Can we create Custom Operating system that supports any application?

Tags: windows, operating-system, linux-from-scratch

Can I create a custom operating system that supports both Windows and Linux applications?

How can I do that and what knowledge should I have?

Is [this](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/development/) a good start?

Thanks.

Comment: There is no possible way to answer this question in the format of this site. You may not get downvotes, but I predict that it will be closed.

Comment: please take the time to read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) before asking questions

Comment: What kind of questions should i ask if want them to get answered?Should i post specific code problems and ask anything about technical problems?thanks

Comment: feel free again to tell me to edit my question again!I am not just curious but this matter really concerns me!

Comment: If you want your questions to be read and paid attention to instead of being frowned upon, at the very least consider using proper spelling (orthography, capitalization, punctuation, spacing, etc) and grammar.

Comment: @gabriel here's an interesting thread on the subject - http://www.reactos.org/forum/viewtopic.php?p=84405

Comment: Sorry i have never gone to school!Sorry alex!Thanks GGG a very first nice comment for my questions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can kind of be done though using Linux and [Wine](http://www.winehq.org/) however it is not perfect.

The issue is Windows is not open source and is **VERY** big so it is not very easy to perfectly emulate what that operating system is doing behind the scenes. This is especially hard with undocumented API calls many programs like to use on Windows.

I do not know of anything that lets you run Mac on Linix without using a VM.

It is very unlikely there will ever be "one OS to rule them all" but with tools like Wine and using virtualization with things like VMWare's [Unity Mode](http://www.codewiz51.com/blog/post/2010/01/24/VMWare-Unity-mode.aspx) to give the affect of another OS's program running on your system.

Comment: Well all i want to understand about it, is why should an OS support only a type of applications?I started the LFS project so that i can figure out how a system is built.So, the idea of combining windows and linux basic tools for a system during the LFS procedure, is not good?thanks very much

Comment: A OS does not support one type of application, a application only supports one type of OS. The OS is the "Language" the app uses to talk to the hardware.